# JavaScript / jQuery on call function event

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there built-in on call function event in JavaScript / jQuery ?

I mean something `on('call' , function(){})`

I use this custom event meanwhile:

```
function setCookie(name, value, days) {
    // set ...
    $(document).trigger( "setCookieEvent", [ name ] );
}
function cookieController()
{
    $(document).on( "setCookieEvent", function( event, name ) {
        //setCookie name
    });
}
cookieController();
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean. You want an event handler called when a different function is invoked?

Comment: no... but, what function do you want to have the event on. you can always create a decorator for the called function.

Comment: @squint Yes, every time function setCookie() called.

Comment: Assuming you can't simply add the call inside `setCookie`, you could cache the function and then replace it with one that invokes your new function as well as the cached one. But if you needed to do this with various handlers that need to be bound and unbound, you'd need to create your own mini event system, which isn't too hard.

Comment: No, but there's always monkey-patching. If it's your implementation, you could also add a custom event handler.

Comment: I'm confused. What is the problem with what you are already doing?

Comment: @matt-ellen just do not want use extra code in setCookie, `$(document).trigger( "setCookieEvent", [ name ] );`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in the comments above, you could decorate the original function with some new functionality. You are essentially saving a reference to the original function, and rewriting the original function to include some new functionality.

```js
function setCookie( name, value, days ) {
  console.log('setCookieCalled ' + name, value, days );
}

setCookie('[before decoration]', 'foo', 1 );

// rewrite the setCookie function
setCookie = decorate(setCookie, function( name, value, days ){
  console.log('decorated setCookie ' + name, value, days );
});

// this will modify the original function. and return a new function that decorates the old.
function decorate(originalFunction, decorator) {
  return function( /* arguments */ ) {
    console.log('called decorator ' + arguments[0] );
    // call the decorator and the original function
    decorator.apply( this, arguments );
    originalFunction.apply( this, arguments );
  }
}

setCookie('[after decoration]', 'bar', 2 );
```

```html
<script src="http://codepen.io/synthet1c/pen/WrQapG.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use jQuery's `event` object:

```js
function setCookie(name, value, days) {
    // set ...
    $.event.trigger({ type: "setCookieEvent", name: name, value: value });
}

function cookieController() {
  $(document).on("setCookieEvent", function(event) {
    document.write("Cookie " + event.name + " created with value " + event.value); 
  });
}


cookieController();

setCookie("cookie-name", "cookie-value", 100);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```